# how to calculate service tax when amount is entered

Tags: jquery

I have written a jquery script which is not working. I need to calculate service tax when the amount is entered. for example amount 100 and service tax 2 percent. Total amount should come automatically.I have written a function and onchange caltax() is written on amount field. Here is my script `function caltax()
    var am=$('#amount').val();
    var ta=$('#tax1per').val();
    var total=(am*ta)/100;
    $('#tax1').val(total);
     };`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `on input` method in jQuery. Here's how to do it:

```js
$("#tax1per, #amount").on('input', function(){
    var am = $('#amount').val();
    var ta = $('#tax1per').val();
    var total = (am * ta) / 100;
    $('#tax1').html(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Amount: <input type="text" id="amount">
<br><br>
Perc: <input type="text" id="tax1per">
<br><hr>
Result: <span id="tax1"></span>
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pf2ud2o5/).

Comment: Hi should i write onchange function on amount field because when written it does not change the value

Comment: I have used the above code and it is not working fine. Any idea why?

Comment: In that case, add more relevant code to your question. From what you've asked, the code I suggested solves the purpose. And btw, `onchange` functions are used for `<select>` HTML elements, not `<input>` elements. Do it exactly as I suggested and it should work.

Comment: Hi the above code works fine however when amount is entered 500 and service tax as 2% the total comes to 10. I need to display total amount as 510. how would it be possible. I.E  add the above two fields and display the total in the third field.

Comment: That is because you are display the amount of service tax applicable on a amount of 500 with 2% tax. You just need to add the Amount (i.e. 500) with total (i.e. 10). That's it.

Comment: Yes of course! Your new answer will be displayed with `$('#tax1').html(total+parseInt(am));` now.

Comment: Hey when amount is entered as 500 and tax as 2% the total is coming as 10500. It should display only 510. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I tried and it is not coming right. It is showing as 10500 and not 510

Comment: I don't know what you're doing but it is working fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/1akjy6cp Sit back and check your code properly.